# How to send a document to a Telegram Bot using pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm trying to develop a Telegram bot using pyTelegramBotAPI package and I need to output multiple documents when user enter an specific /command. I tried below code but it shows an error.

```
    def pca_papers(self, message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Files incoming")
        file = open('https://atikegalle.com/uploads/1514125303.pdf', 'rb')
        bot.send_document(message.chat.id, file)
```

Error:

```
File "C:\Users\pasin\Documents\tgbot\pastpapers.py", line 26, in pca_papers
    file = open('https://atikegalle.com/uploads/1514125303.pdf', 'rb')
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'https://atikegalle.com/uploads/1514125303.pdf'
```

Comment: `'rb'` is used when the file is in your local machine, you seem to providing a link so `'rb'` and `open(..)` isn't needed there. you can just do `bot.send_document(message.chat.id, file=file_url)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) built-in function is for working with local files, not files accessible via HTTP. According to [`send_document` docs](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.send_document) 2nd argument might be

> an HTTP URL as a String for Telegram to get a file from the Internet

so following should work

```
def pca_papers(self, message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Files incoming")
    bot.send_document(message.chat.id, 'https://atikegalle.com/uploads/1514125303.pdf')
```

I do not have ability to test, please try and write if it does works.